# OOP design - How to avoid object type checking

Tags: oop, polymorphism

I have 2 classes, Game and Player, which are both subclassed by various types of games and players, such as PracticeGame, DifficultGame, ExpertPlayer, and NewbiePlayer.

The behavior of game varies depending on the type of player and vice versa. For instance, in DifficultGame the rules are harsher, while NewbiePlayers are cut some breaks and given some extra help.

Is there any way to avoid checking the type of Game in the Player class and checking the type of Player in the Game class? I don't think I can use simple polymorphism as neither of the classes owns the behavior unilaterally; the behavior depends on both of them.

Here is an example that shows the problem. I have if-else statements checking the types of the two objects:

```
class Game:

    do_something:
        for each player:
            if player is NewbiePlayer:
                ...
            else if player is ExpertPlayer:
                ...
            else:
                ...

class Player:

    change_something:
        if game is DifficultGame:
            ...
        else:
            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're suggesting this is not possible, I'd implement simple abstract methods and define them in the sub-classes:

```
class Game:

    do_something:
        for each player:
            player.onDo(this);

    abstract onChange(Player player);


class Player:

    change_something:
        game.onChange(player);

    abstract onDo(Game game);



class DifficultGame:

    onChange(Player player):
        // DifficultGame specific code


class NewbiePlayer:

    onDo(Game game):
        // NewbiePlayer specific code


class ExpertPlayer:

    onDo(Game game):
        // ExpertPlayer specific code
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something. I think this should work.